# Customize order item meta only for WooCommerce admin email notifications

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I need to add custom taxonomy to admin new order emails but not to customer emails. My current code displays my custom taxonomy for each item in the order but it is showing up in both admin and customer emails, which I don't want.

Looking thru `email-order-items.php` I don't see a way to utilize `$sent_to_admin` in the hook that I am using. Am I missing something?

How do I add my custom taxonomy only to admin emails using just hooks and filters?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'custom_woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 10, 3 );

function custom_woocommerce_order_item_meta_end( $item_id, $item, $order ) {
     $product = $item->get_product();

     $locations = get_the_terms( $product->get_id(), 'my_custom_taxonomy' );
     echo '<br/>';
     echo '<div style="margin-top: 20px;">';
     foreach( $locations as $location ) {
          echo 'Location:  <b>' . $location->name . '</b>';
          echo '<br/>';
     }
     echo '</div>
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using `$GLOBAL` variable. I have revisited a bit your code too. Try this:

```
// Setting the "sent_to_admin" as a global variable
add_action('woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'email_order_id_as_a_global', 1, 4);
function email_order_id_as_a_global($order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email){
    $GLOBALS['email_data'] = array(
        'sent_to_admin' => $sent_to_admin, // <== HERE we set "$sent_to_admin" value
        'email_id' => $email->id, // The email ID (to target specific email notification)
    );
}

// Conditionally customizing footer email text
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'custom_email_order_item_meta_end', 10, 3 );
function custom_email_order_item_meta_end( $item_id, $item, $order ){

    // Getting the custom 'email_data' global variable
    $refNameGlobalsVar = $GLOBALS;
    $email_data = $refNameGlobalsVar['email_data'];

    // Only for admin email notifications
    if( ! ( is_array( $email_data ) && $email_data['sent_to_admin'] ) ) return;

    ## -------------------------- Your Code below -------------------------- ##

    $taxonomy = 'my_custom_taxonomy'; // <= Your custom taxonomy

    echo '<br/><div style="margin-top: 20px;">';
    foreach( get_the_terms( $item->get_product_id(), $taxonomy ) as $term )
        echo 'Location:  <b>' . $term->name . '</b><br/>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).*

Tested and works.