# Add custom field (ACF) to WooCommerce completed order email notification

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, email-notifications

There are many threads which deal with the topic "custom fields in WooCommerce emails" but I couldn't find the exact case I am struggling with.

I could achieve 50% of this project to display the field as a meta in the order table.

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'custom_product_info', 20, 4 );
function custom_product_info ( $item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text ) {
    $id = $item->get_product_id();
    $erlebnisidgc = get_field('erlebnis_id',$id);
    if($erlebnisidgc){
        echo "<p>Here's your Link</p><a href=https://b-ceed.de/?eventid='.$erlebnisidgc'>Testlink</a>";
    }
}
```

So this code works perfectly with the custom field. **Problem is** that this output isn't shown only in the `customer_completed_order` email but also in all other emails.

Therefore, I tried this code snippet:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'custom_product_info', 20, 4 );
function custom_product_info ( $item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text ) {
    if ( $email->id == 'customer_completed_order' ) {
        $id = $item->get_product_id();
        $erlebnisidgc = get_field('erlebnis_id',$id);
        if($erlebnisidgc){
            echo "<p>Here's your Link</p><a href=https://b-ceed.de/?eventid='.$erlebnisidgc'>Testlink</a>";
        }
    }
}
```

But now the output won't be displayed in any email anymore and it triggers a internal server error. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

`$email` (`$email->id`) is not passed as argument to the `woocommerce_order_item_meta_end` hook, therefore it is undefined

So to target specific email notifications a workaround will be needed, this can be done by creating a global variable via the `woocommerce_email_before_order_table` hook

So you get:

```php
// Setting global variable
function action_woocommerce_email_before_order_table( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    $GLOBALS['email_data'] = array(
        'email_id'  => $email->id, // The email ID (to target specific email notification)
        'is_email'  => true // When it concerns a WooCommerce email notification
    );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'action_woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 1, 4 );
 
function action_woocommerce_order_item_meta_end( $item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text ) {
    // Getting the custom 'email_data' global variable
    $ref_name_globals_var = $GLOBALS;
    
    // Isset & NOT empty
    if ( isset ( $ref_name_globals_var ) && ! empty( $ref_name_globals_var ) ) {
        // Isset
        $email_data = isset( $ref_name_globals_var['email_data'] ) ? $ref_name_globals_var['email_data'] : '';
        
        // NOT empty
        if ( ! empty( $email_data ) ) {
            // Target specific emails, several can be added in the array, separated by a comma
            $target_emails = array( 'customer_completed_order' );
            
            // Target specific WooCommerce email notifications
            if ( in_array( $email_data['email_id'], $target_emails ) ) {
                // Get product ID
                $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
                
                // Get field
                $erlebnisidgc = get_field( 'erlebnis_id', $product_id );
                
                // Has some value
                if ( $erlebnisidgc ) {
                    echo '<p>Here is your Link</p>';
                    echo '<a href="https://b-ceed.de/?eventid=' . $erlebnisidgc . '">Testlink</a>';
                }
            }           
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'action_woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 10, 4 );
```

---

Used in this answer:

- [Determine only for WooCommerce admin email notification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48344780/11987538)
- [How to target other WooCommerce order emails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61459068/11987538)